# Python ООП передача экземпляра класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

```
class Ingredient(object):

    def __init__(self, name, weight, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.cost = cost

class Pizza(object):

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name



cream = Ingredient('Сыр', 50, 250)
```

Как передать экземпляр класса Ingredient(сream) в класс Pizza и работать там с ним ?

Comment: Добавить в пиццу поле списка ингредиентов, и например при создании объекта передавать их.

Comment: Не очень понял как это будет выглядеть

Comment: вы можете передать в `Pizza` атрибуты экземпляра `Ingridient`, на основе которых создать новый экземпляр

Comment: Передать куда? У вас в пицце нет никакой логики, которая могла бы работать с ингридиентом. И вы даже на словах не описали, что именно должно с этим ингридиентом там происходить. Мы могли бы конечно написать код в котором что-то туда как-то передаётся, но не факт, что это вам чем-то поможет. Хотите получить вменяемый ответ - потрудитесь сформулировать вменяемый вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Также как и любой другой параметр, можно передать и объект пользовательского типа/класса.
Например, так:

```
class Pizza(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # Массив для ингредиетов
        self._ingredients = []

    # Метод для добавления ингредиентов
    def append(self, ingredient):
        self._ingredients.append(ingredient)
```

Далее, где-то в другом месте мы можем создать и добавить ингредиет в Пиццу:

```
# Создаем пиццу
pizza = Pizza('Peperonni')
# Создаем ингредиент
peperone = Ingredient('peperone', 10, 1) # ...Цена указана в рублях :)

# Добавлеям игредиент к пицце
pizza.append(peperone)
```